# Wrote a parser to analyse the site Gumtree.Au, imporporated in telegram bot, but it does not work

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import telebot

# Insert your bot token instead of 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot('I won't show you the Api')

# Handler for the /start command
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Чтобы начать парсинг, нажми кнопку 'Начать парсинг'")

# Parsing the Gumtree.au website
def parse_gumtree():
    url = 'https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-stuff-for-sale/page-1/'
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    products = []
   # Parsing product information
    for ad in soup.find_all('div', class_='user-ad-card-new-design'):
        title = ad.find('a', class_='gallery-listing__thumb')['aria-label']
        price = ad.find('span', class_='gallery-listing__price-currency').text
        views = ad.find('span', class_='vip-ad-header__views').text
        image_url = ad.find('img', class_='user-ad-image')['src']

# Adding a product if it meets the conditions
        if int(views) > 0 and float(price.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')) <= 1000:
            product = {
                'title': title,
                'price': price,
                'views': views,
                'image_url': image_url
            }
            products.append(product)

    return products

# Handler for pressing the "Start Parsing" button
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == 'Начать парсинг')
def start_parsing(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Начинаю парсинг...")

    products = parse_gumtree()

    if len(products) > 0:
        for product in products:
            # Отправляем фото и информацию о товарах
            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, product['image_url'], caption=f"{product['title']}\n"
                                                                          f"Цена: {product['price']}\n"
                                                                          f"Просмотры: {product['views']}\n")                                                                       
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Товаров, удовлетворяющих условиям, не найдено.")

# Start Bot
bot.polling()
```

for some reason the bot is not working, please help me.

The bot just won't start, I don't know what's wrong.
for some reason the bot is not working, please help me.

The bot just won't start, I don't know what's wrong.

for some reason the bot is not working, please help me.

The bot just won't start, I don't know what's wrong.